# Var for component versus class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've noticed a lot of the guides and tutorials online I see:

`var foo = React.createClass`

what is the difference versus what `react-native init` creates which is:

`class foo extends Component`

Is it syntactical? Or are there other differences? What should I be using?

Comment: The first is ES5 syntax, the other is ES6 syntax. Stick with `var foo = React.createClass` unless you know ES6 (or want to learn it).

Comment: Or rather, learn ES6 syntax now?! [In the context of using a modern library and being prepared for the future]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference isn't only syntactic. There are others, such as the class syntax not supporting the mixins feature and not autobinding methods. I recommend you take a look at the [Reusable Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

when you use es5, you should write like this:

```
var foo = React.createClass
```

when you use es6, you should write like this

```
class foo extends Component
```

it is write style for es5 and es6